# Mutate entries in a column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R. Is there a way in which I can clean this column to have all of the "y" or "yes" entries displayed as "Yes" (similarly all the "nop" entries displayed as "No") in dplyr?

```
structure(list(has_elevator = c("Yes", "y", "y", "yes", "y", 
"Yes", "yes", "y", "Yes", "yes", "yes", "Yes", "Yes", "y", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "y", "nop", "Yes", "yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"y", "Yes", "yes", "nop", "yes", "Yes", "nop", "yes", "Yes", 
"y", "y", "Yes", "no", "y", "Yes", "nop", "y", "y", "y", "No", 
"no", "y", "y", "Yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(has_elevator = recode(has_elevator, y = "Yes", nop = "No", no = "No"))`

Comment: I'd imagine you also want to recode the `no` values to `No`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach:
We could use `str_detect` with its argument `ignore_case = T` wrapped in an `ifelse` statement.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(has_elevator  = ifelse(str_detect(has_elevator,  regex('y', ignore_case = T)), "Yes", "No"))
```

```
 has_elevator
1           Yes
2           Yes
3           Yes
4           Yes
5           Yes
6           Yes
7           Yes
8           Yes
9           Yes
10          Yes
11          Yes
12          Yes
13          Yes
14          Yes
15          Yes
16           No
17          Yes
18           No
19          Yes
20           No
21          Yes
22          Yes
23          Yes
24           No
25          Yes
26          Yes
27          Yes
28          Yes
29           No
30          Yes
31          Yes
32           No
33          Yes
34          Yes
35          Yes
36          Yes
37          Yes
38           No
39          Yes
40          Yes
41           No
42          Yes
43          Yes
44          Yes
45           No
46           No
47          Yes
48          Yes
49          Yes
50           No
```

Comment: Important to note the assumptions here: any value starting with the letter "y" should be assumed to be "Yes" while all other non-`NA` values should be "No"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case_when()` within `mutate()` to recode your variable. As I also found that you had some values `no` rather than `No`, I also recoded those for you.

```r
# Your example data
df <- structure(list(has_elevator = c("Yes", "y", "y", "yes", "y", 
                                "Yes", "yes", "y", "Yes", "yes", "yes", "Yes", "Yes", "y", "Yes", 
                                "No", "Yes", "No", "y", "nop", "Yes", "yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                                "y", "Yes", "yes", "nop", "yes", "Yes", "nop", "yes", "Yes", 
                                "y", "y", "Yes", "no", "y", "Yes", "nop", "y", "y", "y", "No", 
                                "no", "y", "y", "Yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                   -50L))
```

## Using `case_when()`

```r
library(dplyr)

# Using case_when()
df_new <- df %>% mutate(
  has_elevator = case_when(
    has_elevator %in% c("y", "yes") ~ "Yes",
    has_elevator %in% c("nop", "no") ~ "No",
    TRUE ~ has_elevator
  )
)

df_new$has_elevator %>% table()
#> .
#>  No Yes 
#>  11  39
```

## Using `recode()`

```r
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>% mutate(
  has_elevator = recode(has_elevator, y = "Yes", yes = "Yes", nop = "No", no = "No")
)

df_new$has_elevator %>% table()
#> .
#>  No Yes 
#>  11  39
```

## Combining string substitution with either function

You can skip recoding values to the proper case with a regular expression that automatically capitalizes the first letter of the string, whatever it is. This avoids possible oversight of case of values.

This is also a `base` approach that doesn't require the `stringr` package.

```r
df_new <- df %>% mutate(
  has_elevator = case_when(
    has_elevator %in% c("y") ~ "Yes",
    has_elevator %in% c("no") ~ "No",
    TRUE ~ has_elevator),
  has_elevator = has_elevator %>% sub('^(\\w?)', '\\U\\1', ., perl=T)
)
```

Comment: To improve this, you could instead use `tolower(substr(has_elevator, 1, 1) == "y"`, and be less reliant on correct input.

Comment: I incorporated the string substitution.